# re2 doesn't change string at all

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I made this code right here on my first try with re2:

```
string s;
RE2::PartialMatch(".+\\.com","http://example.com/", &s);
```

It doesn't work; `s` doesn't change and remains blank.  I could change that first line to `string s = "foo";` and after the second line runs, `s` would stay as `"foo"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think the value should be after you run "foo" through this?

Comment: Fixed example.  But that's not the issue.  I could make the regex "http" and it STILL wouldn't match anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your usage of `PartialMatch`:

1. As already mentioned by Jesse Good, the regex should be the second argument not the first.
2. The pointer arguments to PartialMatch are used to store the substrings matched by the capturing groups of the regular expression. Your regular expression doesn't contain any capturing groups, so nothing is written to the pointer.

This should work:

```
RE2::PartialMatch("http://example.com/", "(.+\\.com)", &s);
```

Or if you don't want s to include the ".com" part:

```
RE2::PartialMatch("http://example.com/", "(.+)\\.com", &s);
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU! xD In a completely platonic, appreciative way.

Answer (score 1):

Try flipping them `RE2::PartialMatch("http://example.com/","example", &s);` It should give you "example" in the string. The first argument is the string you want to search in and the second argument is the pattern.

Comment: No change in behaviour...  I think I might just try some other, more inefficient library.  I just can't find where I'm messing up

Comment: Strange, how about typing `std::cout << RE2::PartialMatch("hello", "ll");`, does that work?

Answer (score 0):

`.\\.com` is wrong regex it capture `anySymbol\.com` and you need same like `/.+\.com`